# Testing if this String init Method Changes a String Into a Different Language?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm going through the string reference documentation because I'm curious to learn what's available or at my disposal.  I'm having trouble implementing a string init method in a playground to see how it works.  I'd like to test if this string init method can accept a string and a locale object to see if the output is a translated string.  Of course I'm using auto complete as a handicap so what I've tried so far is that I attempt to type String.init but the init method I want to test doesn't show up in the list.  How do I use this method?

[Apple reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1779834-init)

Also, I'm familiar with localization.  Again, this was just a test to see how the function works exactly.

```
init(format: String, locale: Locale?, _ args: CVarArg...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `String` initializer doesn't do any language translation. It formats numbers based on the provided locale.

Here's an example using a US English and a Germany German locale:

```
let fmtStrUS = String(format: "%@ %.2f %d", locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US"), "Hello", 1234.5, 12345)
let fmtStrDE = String(format: "%@ %.2f %d", locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE"), "Hello", 1234.5, 12345)
```

The results are:

> Hello 1,234.50 12,345
>   Hello 1.234,50 12.345

Note that the only difference is how the numbers are formatted. No text translation is done.

If you only need to format a number, use a `NumberFormatter`. But if you are localizing more text that includes numbers, this `String` init is the better approach.

This can be combined with standard localization using `NSLocalizedString`.

You may have code something like the following:

```
let messageFormat = NSLocalizedString("Hello %.2f %d", comment: "Fun with localization")
let fullMessage = String(format: messageFormat, locale: Locale.current, someDoubleVariable, someIntVariable)
```

Then in en.strings you would have:

```
"Hello %.2f %d" = "Hello %.2f %d"
```

And in de.strings you would have:

```
"Hello %.2f %d = "Gutentag %.2f %d"
```

So the text translation is done as normal through strings files but this `String` initializer lets you ensure the numbers are formatted for the current user's locale.

Please note that if you use this with `Locale.current` you may wish to use `localizedStringWithFormat` instead which assumes the current locale.

```
let fullMessage = String.localizedStringWithFormat(messageFormat, someDoubleVariable, someIntVariable)
```

Comment: Your implementation helped me realize that I also needed to import Foundation into the playground to see it autocomplete.